# ReactJS undefined arr.map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I´m fetching data from API and then using [arr.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to filter the data* ( API returns unecessary properties )

**This is working:**

```js
       fetchTable() {
        const url = 'http://localhost:8000/issues/assigned/';
        const value = this.state.selectedOption;
        const string = url+value;
        fetch(string)
        .then(function(response) {
          return response.json();
        })
        .then((myJson) => this.setState({data: myJson.issues}));
      }
      
      const filteredResult1 = this.state.data.map(item => (
        {
          name: item.fields ? item.fields.assignee.name : '',
          id: item.id, 
          key: item.key,
          timespent: item.fields ? this.timeConvert(item.fields.timespent) : '',
          project: item.fields ? item.fields.project.name : '',
          status: item.fields ? item.fields.status.name : '',
          created: item.fields ? item.fields.created : '',
          resolution: item.fields ? item.fields.resolutiondate : ''
        }
      ));
```

But now i need to setState multiple times, soo i can render a table for each array with the filtered Data, but the result from map is allways undefined!

```
 .then((myJson) => this.setState({data: [...this.state.data, myJson.issues]}));
```

**This is NOT working:**

```js
   fetchTable() {
        const url = 'http://localhost:8000/issues/assigned/';
        const value = this.state.selectedOption;
        const string = url+value;
        fetch(string)
        .then(function(response) {
          return response.json();
        })
        .then((myJson) => this.setState({data: [...this.state.data, myJson.issues]})); 
      }
      
      
      var result = this.state.data.map((item)=>{ return {id:item.id, example: item.example}; });
      console.log(result)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```js
let array1 = [
  1,2,3
];

let array2 = [
  4,5,6
]
// ...array1 is destructuring array1
// and which leads to an unexpected result
console.log([...array1, array2]);
```

Change this line

```
  .then((myJson) => this.setState({data: [...this.state.data, myJson.issues]}));
```

to this

```
.then((myJson) => this.setState({
    data: this.state.data.concat(myJson.issues)
}));
```

You can find in the code attached that the resulted array is not what you expect.

Comment: Hello @Vasile Florin Vilsan! I´ve done this before, but i dont want to concat them since i will be rendering a table for each array!

Comment: Then can you please provide sample data for the this.state.data and myJson.issues  in `[...this.state.data, myJson.issues]`

Comment: I have a multi-select as you can see `const value = this.state.selectedOption;`, initially this.state.data is empty! 
then for each selected option, it will fetch data into this.state.data!

Comment: Can you please provide `this.state.data` and  `myJson.issues` in `[...this.state.data, myJson.issues]`, from the second time you run the request.

Comment: i´m sorry but i´m not getting the point! 
I´ve uploaded an image on the third time running the request.

Comment: Not being able to see the structure of the returned and `merged` data, doesn't help me help you. As far as I can see with the provisioned you are not merging the current data, with the newly fetched data properly, This creates inconsistency in the new state data over which you map. If any of the item.id or item.example in `var result = this.state.data.map((item)=>{ return {id:item.id, example: item.example}; })` are undefined, then this may cause the map to return undefined